# JSON spreadsheet returns null, or am I an idiot

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

So, have been trying to get a javascript to read a spreadsheet, but needed it private rather than public, so spent quite a bit of time trying to figure out how to do that. It is actually quite easy, or seems like it is, except that I still can't read the spreadsheet. Will cover private spreadsheets through the cloud console in the end.

So, I have a rather simple spreadsheet which contains about 6 columns, (including customer emails and similar, hence why private). And I have been playing about trying to get it to work for the last couple of days.

First, the string!
So to enable this I first need a string that will return a json object (is that what I am expecting back?)
https address: https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/ 
Sheet ID     : 
Additional   : /od6/private/full
Command      : ?alt=json-in-script&callback=importGSS

or full string : https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list//od6/private/full?alt=json-in-script&callback=importGSS

This seems to work quite fine, if I remove the json part it shows me the data sheet, if I ad it, I get an empty file instead.

So now to the code.
The function that SHOULD be returning the object is the following (spLink) contains the link above.

```
function loadData(spLink){
$.getJSON(spLink).always(function(data) {
    console.log("Object created!");
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function(message) {
    console.error('Something went pretty wrong!');
    console.error(message);
}).done(function(){
    console.log('Done!');
});
```

}

The only thing I can really tell about it is that data continues returning null, and I can't really figure out where else the data may end up.
Have tried both with and without callback.

Comment: This is not app script tag.

Answer (score 0):

The list feed only works if there are no empty  cells in a row with data, among other pitfalls.
Use the cell feed instead, which requires more code because you wont get the data organized by rows.

Comment: Tried cells, with no luck, also tried breaking the key, just give a faulty one. Still get null on the ling, and if I try to open the page I get an empty file back, guessing that is because it returns a file handle or similar as an object.

Comment: But if I change the address then it does fail, so the JSON calls built in error check does react to some things, like changing the address to googliereier.com. So something is working, or at least does not know that it is not working, which is completely different.

Comment: The api is certainly not failing. Try it from the oauth2 playground.

Comment: are you executing this in  a way that will do the necessary oauth2? Use firebug or chrome tool to see what is going on with the get.

Comment: I am pretty certain oauth is sorted, I can access the file following the link, and I have answered the question from google if I want to allow the access.

Comment: Followed the model from this article http://developer.gooddata.com/article/cloudconnect-downloading-data-from-google-spreadsheet. I am now starting to wonder if I am going to try using grails to develop what I want, as there is some additional functions that is likely to be a who lot simpler in a java app, and possibly I can use the spreadsheet as an object (or two) for both getting rows and updating them. The whole reason I am doing this is to supercharge a spreadsheet and let people check part of the information and update another sheet. Database could have worked.